# Isolated and Reproducible Development Environment (X Forwarding + Docker)

Tags: python, matplotlib, docker, x11

Is there a way to run:

- Interactive Python (direct python/ipython, not Jupyter notebook with a remote connection)
- Matplotlib
- Display graphs

**within** a Docker container, while displaying graphics on the **host** using X Forwarding (or any other alternative)?

For example, I would like to be able to interactively run the following code on the **container** (line by line):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 1])
plt.show()
```

and see the resulting figure on the **host**.

Comment: Both graphical and interactive applications are not the typical usecases for Docker. It is possible to do but may I ask why it has to run in Docker?

Comment: @klaus-d I would like to have an isolated and reproducible development environment.  For example, a container with custom builds of opencv and tensorflow.  When debugging/running the applications in that container, they display graphs, frames of videos, etc.